# UK visitor visa refused. Tax return and business account not considered as proof of income

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My parents' visitor visa was refused and here is the full scenario.

My father is self-employed and hence earns yearly profit and doesn't draw a monthly salary. He doesn't have regular deposits in any of his savings accounta, and all his transactions are carried out via his business account.

He was self-sponsoring the trip as we were planning to sponsor my in-laws. As a proof of funds he submitted his business account details and one savings account detail. Unfortunately the saving account has a single lump sum transaction and the balance is low.

They didn't mention the business account in the refusal letter at all. He provided an IT return file which they termed as "self-declared" and "self-completed".
His income is not fixed hence the income quoted was an estimated one and his IT returns shows that even though he quoted say INR 40k per month, last year it was 30k per month and last to last year it was 35k per month. His income tax is audited by a chartered accountant.

Also he estimated the cost of the trip at 2.5 times of the monthly income.
He had submitted property tax receipts as proof of property and trade license as proof of employment. They are asking for "proof of income".

Mother's refusal

She is a housewife and she was being sponsored by my dad. Since in the form the column of income from other sources like investment and savings were written null, they didn't consider her fixed deposits and savings account details (which has a decent amount maintained for more than a year). She has no property in her name.

I am their only child and my maternal grandmother is alive.

We don't have our spouse's name in me and my husband's passports. But we do have marriage certificate and affidavit stating that I can use both my husband's surname and my maiden name.

My father has intimation notice of his IT returns system generated by IT department and digitally signed by IT officer which acknowledges his IT returns. (it is different from the IT return file receipt that he submitted).

He has more than enough money in his business account but we do understand that business account is not considered as proof of income.

Our own visa is only valid for exactly a year more as we have to leave after 12 months.

My husband can sponsor them easily and we wish to apply again after 2 months.

[image: Image of a UKVI refusal notice]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: No, it is mentioned in the post of the link to provide IT return and here in my father's case IT return is overlooked for being "self assessed and self completed ". He provided acknowledgement of the filed return, that it has been accepted. Still it was not considered.

Comment: The filed return _was_ considered, but was found not persuasive because the information was "self assessed and self completed." UKVI is looking for confirmation from other sources (banks, for instance) that confirm a stable and continuing source of income, and sufficient funds to reasonably make the proposed expenditure. This thread has more information regarding VKVI's view of bank accounts: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: It's extremely common for visas to be refused for people who use their business accounts for personal expenses. The first step would be to separate these clearly and have the business pay you a salary.

Comment: You should be able to get an annual tax statement from the authorities in your country which matches up with your self assessment tax returns - thats one of the official documents the UK are looking for.

Comment: Even if he draws a salary now, wont it take 6 months bank statement atleast? We wanted to reapply after 2 months.

Comment: In addition to the issue with the absence of a personal account and actual transfers from the business to the personal account, his revenue is quite low by UK standards, and it would seem that a) it would be difficult for him to justify the expense of paying for the trip for him and your mother (2.5 times monthly income must mean a lot more compared to available revenue once you factor in living costs) and b) it would not show enough ties to the country, even working illegally in the UK he would probably make more, so he would be considered at risk of trying to overstay.

Comment: a) What if I sponsor him? I have means to do so. b) his yearly income is average in Indian standards and business doesn't guarantee same level of income every year. And since our visa is getting over by feb 2021, wont it be reason enough to return? He is 63 year old bdw.

Comment: @shreyash If you submit another application very quickly after a refusal, it’s possible/likely that a further refusal will result even with you as a sponsor, unless the original refusal reasons have also been addressed.

Comment: @traveller is a gap of 6 months good enough?

Comment: @shreyash There’s no way to know that for sure. Possibly/probably if you deal with the separation of business & personal bank accounts, provide tax returns for recent years and document the source of any unusual transactions, and submit an impeccable application. If you can afford it, it may be worth paying for an immigration lawyer to check the application before it’s submitted https://www.gov.uk/find-an-immigration-adviser